# Minimum number of edges to ensure connectedness

Tags: graph-theory, proof-verification

Question: Consider a simple graph G with n vertices. What is the minimum number of edges that G must have in order to ensure that it is connected? Justify your answer.

My attempt: Let G = $(V, E)$. Consider a vertex $v \in E$. If G is connected, it is necessary that there is a path from $v$ to each of the remaining $n-1$ vertices. Suppose each path consists of a single edge. This adds up to a minimum of $n-1$ edges. Since $v$ is now connected to every vertex, we see that there is a path between any two vertices $via$ $v$. Therefore G is connected and we are done. So a minimum of $n-1$ edges is required.

Is this a valid proof? Or am I missing something?

EDIT: Based on D Poole's answer, I should seek to maximize the expression $\binom{a}{2} + \binom{n-a}{2} + 1$, where $a$ and $n-a$ are the respective number of vertices in the two components.
Let $f(a) = \frac{a(a-1)}{2} + \frac{(n-a)(n-a-1)}{2} = \frac{2a^2 - 2na + n^2 - n}2$
$\frac{df}{da} = \frac{4a - 2n}2$.
Let $\frac{df}{da} = 0.$ Then $a = \frac n2$.
Applying the first derivative test we see that when $a = \frac n2$, $f(a)$ is maximum.
If n is even then there is no problem. If n is odd then should we take $\lfloor \frac n2 \rfloor$ or $\lceil \frac n2 \rceil$?

Comment: You proof is ok

Comment: as D Poole's answer below says, this is likely not proving what the question is asking for: you've shown that n-1 is the smallest number of edges *among all connected n-vertex graphs*, but you have not shown that having n-1 edges *ensures* that the graph is connected

Comment: I see what you mean! How should I approach this question then?

Comment: D Poole is doing a thorough job of explaining that, but I feel I should clarify one more point: on closer examination, I think this is not actually a valid proof that every $n$-vertex connected graph has $n-1$ edges. in particular, when you say "If G is connected, it is necessary that there is a path from v to each of the remaining n−1 vertices. Suppose each path consists of a single edge. This adds up to a minimum of n−1 edges" you seem to be ignoring the possibility that these paths can *share* edges.

Comment: There are in total n-1 paths from v to each of the n-1 vertices. Each path, by definition, must have at least 1 edge. If we consider the bare minimum, that is, each path has exactly 1 edge, then we have n-1 distinct edges.

Comment: Here's the issue with that argument. For each $w \neq v$, fix a $v,w$-path $P_w$. You are trying to argue that $|\bigcup E(P_w)| \geq \sum |E(P_w)| \geq n-1$ since each $|E(P_w)| \geq 1$. In general, the first inequality in that chain is not true. (Of course it will turn out to be true that $|\bigcup E(P_w)| \geq n-1$, but you would need to argue it some other way.)

Comment: Is that because in general, not all $P_w$ are "disjoint"?

Answer (score 4):

You show that you can have a graph with $n-1$ edges and be connected. I read the problem as finding the $m$ below:
$$
m= \min\{M: \text{ if }G\text{ is a graph on }n \text{ vertices and }M \text{ edges, then }G \text{ is connected}\}.
$$
Since there are graphs with $n-1$ edges with $n$ vertices that are NOT connected, $m$ should be larger.

EDIT: How to find this $m$?

A graph $G$ is connected if there is NOT a proper subset $A \subset V(G)$, $1 \leq |A| \leq n-1$ such that there are no edges between $A$ and $A^c$. In particular, for a connected graph $G$ and all subsets of vertices $A$ with $1 \leq |A| \leq n-1$, there is an edge between $A$ and $A^c$.

For a fixed subset $A$, how many edges can be present so that there are no edges between $A$ and $A^c$? We can have a complete graph on $A$ and a complete graph on $A^c$ but no edges between these two subgraphs. So we can have 
$${|A| \choose 2}+{n-|A| \choose 2}$$
potential edges in this disconnected graph. Conversely, if $G$ has at least 
$${|A| \choose 2}+{n-|A| \choose 2}+1$$
edges, then necessarily there is an edge between $A$ and $A^c$. Consequently, taking the maximum over all $|A|$, we have that
$$
m = \max_a {a \choose 2}+{n-a \choose 2} +1.
$$
When is this expression maximized?

Comment: I should add that $n \geq 4$.

Comment: You are right! A graph with 4 vertices could contain a 3-cycle and still not be connected. How should I approach this question then?

Comment: Why maximize m when we are trying to find the minimum m?

Comment: Oh, I see now. We need to find the maximum number of edges in a graph with two connected components. Since it is a simple graph, we cannot have any parallel edges. So any edge we add will then join the two components together and ensure that G is connected. But somehow when I'm using calculus I can only find a minimum which occurs at a = $\frac{n}{2}$, I think I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Yes you are getting it. For $G$ to be connected, for all subsets of vertices $A$, there must be an edge from $A$ to $A^c$. The max over $a$ does occur when $a=n/2$ (if $n$ is odd, consider $a=\lceil n/2 \rceil$ and $a=\lfloor n/2 \rfloor$). Note that this says that the worst possible case is when we have two large complete subgraphs with equal number of vertices.

Comment: Thanks, you really helped me out. Did you come up with the solution yourself? I myself would never have been able to come up with a solution like that; maybe it's because I find graph theory too unintuitive.

Comment: @Vizuna First, I made a mistake in my earlier comment, the worst case is when $a=1$, when there is a single isolated vertex. This problem is commonly discussed in a introduction to extremal graph theory. I have no idea who first proved it.

Comment: How do we arrive at the value $a = 1$?

Comment: Suppose $f(a)={a \choose 2}+{n-a \choose 2}=\frac{a^2-a}{2}+{(n-a)^2-(n-a)}{2}$. So $f'(a)=a-\frac{1}{2}-(n-a)+\frac{1}{2}=2a-n$. In particular, $f'(a)<0$ for $a<n/2$ and $f'(a)>0$ for $a>n/2$. Thus the maximum for $f(x)$ for $x\in[1,n-1]$ occurs at either $x=1$ or $x=n-1$. Note that $f(1)=f(n-1)$.

Comment: Doesn't the first derivative test show that the maximum occurs at $a = \frac n2$? How did you get from $\frac n2$ to the values $1$ and $n-1$?

Comment: $f$ is decreasing on $[1, n/2]$, because $f'$ is negative on that interval. So the max on $[1, n/2]$ occurs at the left endpoint $a=1$.